# Removing content between brackets in text file

Tags: python

I am trying to print out the content of a file (a movie script) but deleting every content that is between parenthesis or brackets (including the brackets and parenthesis themselves).

Here is what I have so far:

```
import re

file = open('filename','r', encoding="utf-8", errors='ignore')

newfile = file.read()

test = re.sub(r'\([^()]*\)', '', output)
```

It seems like it deletes everything contained in parenthesis, but not for brackets. Any help ?

Comment: @DavyM: yes but that is not the problem here.

Comment: I've tested it with a sample string, and it works. Perhaps a problem is that the file contains double brackets (like `foo ((bar)) qux`).

Comment: The file does not contained double brackets

Comment: can you provide a (short) sample of a file, together with the output you obtain?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem apparently not ;)

Comment: I actually figured it out ahah ! I replaced it with r'[\(\[].*?[\)\]]' and it works for now !

Answer (score 2):

You just need to modify your regex a touch. You're not doing anything to include brackets, by which I assume you mean `[` and `]`. You see, the brackets in your current regex are used to match one of each of the things inside it. The `^` actually means not to match those. Your program should look something like:

```
import re

with open('filename') as f:
    newfile = f.read()

test = re.sub(r'[\(\[].*[\)\]]', '', newfile)
```

[Try it out](https://regex101.com/r/xpD90e/2)

Answer (score 1):

Without using regular expressions:

```
newfile = '''teceft\n frhbfhr(jnjf(frfjrf)vrfhfr)fjnrf\nfrjkerjk(fewnjrfn)ebhjfbwrf\nrbhfhw[fhbewhf]fewhf\n'''

pas = False
count = 0
output = []
for elem in newfile:
  if elem in ("(","["):
    count += 1
    pas = True
  elif elem in (")","]"):
    count -= 1
    if count == 0: pas = False
  elif not pas:
    output.append(elem)
output = "".join(output)
print (output)
```

Output:

```
teceft
 frhbfhrfjnrf
frjkerjkebhjfbwrf
rbhfhwfewhf
```